# Android Browser doesn't connect to socket

Tags: javascript, android, sockets

Using the following code to load my webapp inside the android browser

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    browser.loadUrl("http://website:56/apps/liverarefeed");
```

The issue is it won't connect to the socket as defined in the javascript of the page

```
var socketio = io.connect("website:56");
```

Opening that url in Chrome, Dolphin, Samsung's Browser or HTC's will connect just fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't enable Javascript, adding this code fixed the issue.

```
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```